# Create a text file 1 by 1 and save it to directory

Tags: batch-file

I have this command:

```
For /l %%n in (1,1,1) do echo welcome >> "C:\Users\Documents\Backup\TestingFile%%n.txt"
```

It creates a file and when you run it the next time it overwrites. It should create a file on each run.
For instance you run a script for two times it should 2 files but it does not.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: `>>` appends to the specified file. if you want to replace a previous file, use `>` instead.

Comment: The only variable in your file name is `%%n` which will always be the same (1 in this case, but if you run the loop from 1-5, it will always be these values) so the same file name will be used. You need to introduce more variables (for example a timestamp) if you want to produce new files each time.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner could you please help me in adding a timestamp variable for 2 min using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you are asking the FOR command to count...

starting from one

stepping by one

ending at one.

So the FOR is doing what you *asked* it to, so getting just one file kind of makes sense.  Let's ignore the file output part for a moment and see what the FOR is doing.

Here is an excerpt from the FOR command/s help text:

```
C:\tmp>for /?
...etc...
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
    The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
    So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
    generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Just for fun, let's skip the "write to a file part" and look at what the for loops are doing...
The original for loop is first with Welcome, then a slightly modified one with "more welcome"
Make sense?

```
C:\tmp>type foo.bat
echo off
For /l %%n in (1,1,1) do echo welcome, n=%%n
For /l %%n in (1,1,3) do echo ** more welcome, n=%%n **


C:\tmp>foo.bat

C:\tmp>echo off
welcome, n=1
** more welcome, n=1 **
** more welcome, n=2 **
** more welcome, n=3 **
C:\tmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the batch file to create a new file each time it is run you will need to check for the existence of all the previous files first.

```
@echo off
set num=0
:LOOP
set /a num+=1
IF EXIST "C:\Users\Documents\Backup\TestingFile%num%.txt" GOTO LOOP
echo welcome >"C:\Users\Documents\Backup\TestingFile%num%.txt"
```

The flaw in this code though is that if you have 4 files created and someone deletes file 2 or 3, the next time it runs it will create that file instead of file 5.

Comment: if i want a user to name a file while creating it.Could you u please tell how can i allow a user to name that file? thankyou  for the code

Comment: @emraan, you can use the `SET` command with the `/P` option to prompt for user input. http://ss64.com/nt/set.html